# cufon.js conflict with fabric.js

Tags: jquery-plugins, cufon, fabricjs

I am using cufon.js to render some text.  The text is NOT in a fabric canvas which also exists on the page. Removing fabric.js allows the text to be rendered OK, but breaks when I put fabric.js back.  The script to render the text is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Cufon.replace('#signature');
</script>
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATED:**

These are the script links I have on the page (fabric.js is all.min.js version 1.1.0 found in the dist folder)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/fabric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I'm using fabric version 0.9.15...

Comment: Does this happen with more recent versions? 1.1.0 for example https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/tags

Comment: That is not the same link used at the bottom of http://fabricjs.com/ where it says 'download latest version'.  Anyway the issue persistes with 1.1.0 using the scripts links updated in the OP (fabric.js is all.min.js found in the dist folder).

Comment: Also noticed with 1.1.0 that I can't rotate objects whereas in 0.9.15 rotation was automatically enabled.

Comment: Yes, the rotation is now separate from scaling in version 1+. As far as Cufon issue, need to look into it. Please file a bug on github.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render all font replaces. Look this:

```
$("#signature").change(function(e){
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if(object && object.type == "text"){
        object.fontFamily = $(this).val();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
});
```

Or

```
Cufon.replace('#signature', {fontFamily: '<font_name>'});
```

Check this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ptCoder/tcVUt/